# What is the specific type of the JSON being sent to a Webhook?

Tags: json, spring-boot, jira, webhooks

I can register a so called *webhook* in JIRA if I want JIRA to inform an external application about changes. Some JSON is generated when an issue is changed and sent to the webhook. 
Is this JSON ...just a Stirng...or is it the representation of a specific Java class? If this would be the case: which class is it? 
Or: how to I have to handle this JSON when it is sent to my SpringBoot application (webhook)? Just as a String or can I map this JSON via Jackson to a particular class...and how do I have to do this?

Answer (score 0):

[A callback for an issue-related event is structured like this](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/webhooks?_ga=2.24366906.1807915839.1513004122-954611890.1513004122#Webhooks-Example:callbackforanissue-relatedevent)...